# Error installing ruby on rails on mac osx 10.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos

I am first time installing Ruby on Rails on a Mac OSX 10.8 machine and it is generating the following error :-

> Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/tcs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392 --with-opt-    dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libxml2:/usr/local/opt/libxslt:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl:/usr/local/opt/sqlite --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
>   please read /Users/tcs/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/1366722478_configure.log
>   There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.

I have read lot of blogs and articles but this error sticks every time I try to install RoR.

I have Xcode 4.6 installed on the Mac.

Comment: What's in the log file it tells you to look at?

Comment: @DaveNewton, It says C compiler cannot create executables.

Comment: ... Wouldn't it make sense to include the error so people could actually attempt a diagnosis?

Answer (score 0):

if the c compiler can't creat executables you probably just need to install the Xcode command line tools.